# MySQL statement to get data from one table depending on another tabel

Tags: mysql

I have these two tables

[image]

I need a MySQL statement that if a spot has 2 or more rows in the facility table.
Lets say that I need to find spots that has both shower and toilet.

I have tried with something like this

```
select * 
from spot 
where spot.id IN (
                    select spot_id 
                    from facility 
                    where facility LIKE 'shower' 
                    AND facility LIKE 'toilet'
                )
```

But the subselect doesn't return anything while title can't be both 'shower' AND 'toilet'.

Edit:
I got this working

select *
from spot
where spot.id IN (
select spot_id
from facility
where facility LIKE 'toilet'
)
AND spot.id IN (
select spot_id
from facility
where facility LIKE 'shower'
)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use OR instead of AND or you can use IN or we can use Join as well.

```
select * from spot where spot.id IN (
     select spot_id from facility where facility IN ('shower','toilet'));
```

or

```
select * from spot where spot.id IN (
     select spot_id from facility where facility LIKE 'shower'
    OR facility LIKE 'toilet');
```

or

```
select s.id, s.title from spot s join facility f on s.id = f.spot_id where f.facility in ('shower','toilet');
```

Comment: But that wil not give me spot with shower AND toilet.

Comment: @Jeppe I think as per your table structure both "shower" and "toilet" in a one row is not possible right. Can you please share your sample data?